# Conditional Running Count Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am attempting to create a conditional running sum in pandas based on two conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
ID = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4]
after = ['A','B','B','A','A','B','A']
before = ['A','B','B','A','A','B','A']
df = pd.DataFrame([ID, before,after]).T
df.columns = ['ID','before','after']
```

The data looks like:

```
   ID before after
0  1      A     A
1  1      B     B
2  1      B     B
3  2      A     A
4  2      A     A
5  3      B     B
6  4      A     A
```

I then want to look at how long an ID has had the value of before as B, my attempt:

```
df['time_on_b'] = (df.groupby('before')['ID'].cumcount()+1).where(df['before']=='B',0)
```

This gives me:

```
    ID before after  time_on_b
0  1      A     A          0
1  1      B     B          1
2  1      B     B          2
3  2      A     A          0
4  2      A     A          0
5  3      B     B          3
6  4      A     A          0
```

The ideal output is as followed:

```
   ID before after  time_on_b
0  1      A     A          0
1  1      B     B          1
2  1      B     B          2
3  2      A     A          0
4  2      A     A          0
5  3      B     B          1
6  4      A     A          0
```

As you can see as the ID changes I want time_on_b to reset so it gives me the value of 1 and not 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you need to group by `ID`, then use `cumsum` to count the occurrences of `B`:

```
cond = df.before == 'B'
df['time_on_b'] = cond.groupby(df.ID).cumsum().where(cond, 0).astype(int)
df
#  ID   before  after   time_on_b
#0  1        A      A   0
#1  1        B      B   1
#2  1        B      B   2
#3  2        A      A   0
#4  2        A      A   0
#5  3        B      B   1
#6  4        A      A   0
```

Comment: Get my work done, +1. Anyway, is `cond.groupby(df.ID)` as same as `df[df.before == 'B'].groupby('ID')`?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `transform` like

```
df.groupby('ID').before.transform(lambda x: x.eq('B').cumsum())

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    0
Name: before, dtype: int32

df.assign(time_on_b=df.groupby('ID').before.transform(lambda x: x.eq('B').cumsum()))

   ID before after  time_on_b
0   1      A     A          0
1   1      B     B          1
2   1      B     B          2
3   2      A     A          0
4   2      A     A          0
5   3      B     B          1
6   4      A     A          0
```